# Sendding JSON to REST WebService - java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException

Tags: java, json, web-services, rest

i've wrote a REST web-service for accepting json array from client but i'm getting `java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException`

can anyone please tell me some solution for this

**Client**

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try{
        ClientConfig config = new DefaultClientConfig();
        Client client = Client.create(config);
        client.addFilter(new LoggingFilter());
        HashMap dados=new HashMap();
        WebResource service = client.resource("http://localhost:8224/SampleREST/REST/WebService/MyReceive");
        JSONObject data= new JSONObject();
        dados.put("Name", "John");
        dados.put("Age", "30");
        dados.put("City", "Tokyo");
        data.accumulate("ss", dados);
        ClientResponse client_response = service.accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).post(ClientResponse.class, data);

        System.out.println("Status: "+client_response.getStatus());

        client.destroy();
        }catch(Exception s){s.printStackTrace();}
    }

}
```

**Server**

```
 @POST
        @Path("/MyReceive")

        @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
        @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)

        //Receive and send a json object
        public JSONObject receiveJSONObject(JSONObject json) throws JSONException
        {
            System.out.println(json.toString());
               return json;
        }
```

**Exception getting**

```
1 * Out-bound request
1 > POST http://localhost:8224/SampleREST/REST/WebService/MyReceive
1 > Accept: application/json
1 > 
com.sun.jersey.api.client.ClientHandlerException: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0
    at com.sun.jersey.client.urlconnection.URLConnectionClientHandler.handle(URLConnectionClientHandler.java:128)
    at com.sun.jersey.api.client.filter.LoggingFilter.handle(LoggingFilter.java:152)
    at com.sun.jersey.api.client.Client.handle(Client.java:397)
    at com.sun.jersey.api.client.WebResource.handle(WebResource.java:557)
    at com.sun.jersey.api.client.WebResource.access$300(WebResource.java:69)
    at com.sun.jersey.api.client.WebResource$Builder.post(WebResource.java:499)
    at webService.Test.main(Test.java:35)
Caused by: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0
    at java.util.ArrayList.rangeCheck(ArrayList.java:604)
    at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:382)
    at com.sun.jersey.api.client.TerminatingClientHandler.writeRequestEntity(TerminatingClientHandler.java:293)
    at com.sun.jersey.client.urlconnection.URLConnectionClientHandler._invoke(URLConnectionClientHandler.java:179)
    at com.sun.jersey.client.urlconnection.URLConnectionClientHandler.handle(URLConnectionClientHandler.java:126)
    ... 6 more
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `@FormParam` to consume the POST body params. Try changing this:

```
    public JSONObject receiveJSONObject(JSONObject json) throws JSONException
```

to

```
    public JSONObject receiveJSONObject(@FormParam("") JSONObject json) throws JSONException
```

Comment: @user2040500 you are not able to map the post param to your input param. try setting a name to the param in the client and use the same name in the method FormParam attribute namem

Comment: @JunedAhsan........yes i've i did.......... data.accumulate("ss", dados);.............in the client side ........public JSONObject receiveJSONObject(@FormParam("ss") JSONObject json) throws JSONException..........still geting same exception

Comment: sir ....what will be the problem ........ why it is still showing the same exception